# Different caption styles for figures and for tables

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I need to have different caption format for figures and for tables. Captions for figures have to be centered and captions for tables - left aligned. How to define this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and its `justification=raggedright` option. If desired, add `singlelinecheck=false` to make sure that single-line captions are also typeset raggedright.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Optional: float content (apart from caption) centered
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
(Tabular material)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `caption` allows exactly this.

```
\captionsetup[figure]{....}
\captionsetup[table]{....}
```